# In a RESTful JSON api is it valid to use PUT to update a resource that includes a LastModified timestamp

Tags: json, rest, put

The resource representation contains various data plus a lastModified field that will be set by the server

```
{
    someData:data,
    lastModified:"timestamp"
}
```

when GETting the resource the lastModified field will be included, so a PUT would include it, however the server will update lastModified overriding whatever value was in the PUT.

My instinct is to say that either the lastModified field has to be removed from the resource representation at this url (not really an option) or a POST must be used with the representation including the lastModified field which will then be ignored and overridden by the server

So... is it actually OK to use PUT in this case - or must I fall back to POST.

(NB this is being looked at as an alternative to using PATCH with the JSON patch spec as this is turning out to be inefficient for our use cases)

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, and one of the few doubts about REST for which I couldn't find any standardized definition, so I decided to go with what makes more sense. I opened this question months ago, it might give you some ideas:

[Using the PUT method with incomplete representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825870/using-the-put-method-with-incomplete-representations)

The core issue here is whether the server is allowed to fill in defaults for missing values on an incomplete representation sent on a `PUT` request. It's clear that the server can't perform partial updates on a `PUT`, but it's also clear how the server can have default values that can't be mandatory and are completely under server control.

In the absence of an answer backed by the standards, the solution I adopted was:

1. The server should accept an incomplete representation and fill missing values with defaults, that should be documented as media-type defaults.
2. The server should throw an error when the client sends a field that is completely under server control.
3. Because some developers might confuse that with partial updates, it needs to be clearly documented, with a warning, and pointing to `PATCH` for partial updates.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hugely clear from the question why you think the timestamp is important to the choice of HTTP verb. As the resource already exists on the server then it should probably be a PUT. This assumes that the target URL uniquely identifies the resource. If however the URL represents a collection then a POST would be more appropriate. Particularly if the combination of someData and lastModified will be interpreted as new, unique resource by the server.