# Super simple definition/explanation of "REST"

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Can someone define/breakdown REST for me? In the contexts of API's and programming. But with like super specific language where I don't need to pull out a dictionary for all the other words.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you even google before asking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551933/can-you-explain-the-web-concept-of-restful

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw that one beforehand but at 4AM my time, I was looking for something in 2-3 sentences. I understand what it is but I'll just try to translate it into baby language if I need to reference it later.