# Is Web API and Service synonymous in web development world?

Tags: web-services, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to web programming, and every now and then I get confused with different terminologies that are used. I was going through ASP.NET Web API, and I noticed a lot of articles, courses says things like `Creating RESTful web api with ASP.NET Web API 2` etc. What they are doing is implementing the GET, POST, PUT, DELETE methods. So basically they are exposing data services to the client, right? How come that be an API (Application Programming Interface)?

The http://www.asp.net/web-api site says, `ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that...`

So, I got confused again. Are the terms "API" and "Service" synonymous in web programming paradigm? Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT :** I think my question remained somewhat unclear. So, to clarify -

From different sources I'm having the following two different concepts on ASP.NET Web API, yet they all are implementing the same thing -

1. ASP.NET Web API is used to create Web APIs
2. ASP.NET Web API is used to create HTTP Services

Now, I do know what an API is, and what Services (or Web Services) are. I'm asking the question from purely Web development perspective, since I'm totally new to this Web programming arena.

So, are the terms API (or Web API) and Service used interchangeably or synonymous in Web development (in general, or in .NET Web development)?

Comment: Basically, API is a layer between your backend and frontend, all this parts can provide some service to your customers/users. Also with API you can give some parts of functionality for other developers to work with it. F.e. we got DB that stores some business data, we have an API that provides that data on our frontends and is backend for other department services/backends etc. This is how I understand API/service paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

## API

An API (Application Programming Interface) is **a tool** for building applications and services. The API usually returns a structured response (usually XML or JSON) of some data.

## Example

Let's say you have a simple table of customers in a database:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
| id | firstName | lastName |          email          |    phone     | createDate |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Marc      | Johnson  | marc.jo@hotmail.com     | 202-555-0112 | 2016-09-03 |
|  2 | James     | Jackson  | jojgo@gmail.com         | NULL         | 2014-05-02 |
|  3 | Joe       | Smith    | joe.smith35@hotmail.com | NULL         | 2015-12-12 |
|  4 | Julie     | Brown    | smjuli@yahoo.com        | 202-555-0192 | 2014-01-29 |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

You would create API's to perform the following actions:

- Get all customer info (GET)
- Retrieve customer info by id (GET)
- Create new customer (POST)
- Delete customer (DELETE)
- Edit customer (PUT)

## RESTful

The term RESTful refers to a way of building API's. Check out the top answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551933/can-you-explain-the-web-concept-of-restful) for an excellent definition.

## Accessibility

An API can be directly accessable by clients (public API). Sometimes they're accessable to the public without authentication, other times they require an API-key to validate that you have permission to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not synonymous. An API is a contract/specification how to use another component, library or system; so it is a very broad concept. The word service itself is rather overloaded with a lot of different meanings.

In the case of a webservice, the webservice is/provides an API (or at least: an implementation of an API), but that does not mean that all API are (web)services.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use  Services, API and Web API interchangeably. They all are different. But you may use Web APIs and Web Services interchangeably.

***In short:***

**API:** API stands for Application Programming Interface which is a protocol used as an interface by software components to communicate with each other. An API serves as an interface between two different applications so that they can communicate with each other. In this way all web services are APIs, so API is a broader concept.

**Web Services / Web APIs :**
Technically, all web services / web APIs are APIs, additionally, these APIs communicate over a network (like world wide web) through HTTP between the two systems.

**Services:** Services have many different meanings depend upon the context in which they are talking about.